# Javascript OOP: Object with Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I have two objects. I would like the second object to contain an array of the first object but am having no luck.

Example:

```
function objectOne(val)
{
    this.a = val;
    this.b = val;
}

function objectTwo()
{
    this.arr = []; //should be an array of object one
    this.loadArray = loadArray;

    function loadArray()
    {
       //right here I am iterating through sharepoint list items
         var obj1 = new objectOne(4, "foo");
         this.arr.push(obj1);
    }
}

var obj2 = new objectTwo();
obj2.loadArray();
```

It doesn't seem to matter what way I try and load the objectOnes into the array of objectTwo, it always returns with an undefined or null reference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where's the code showing how you've tried to make use of those two functions?

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand what you're asking, perhaps because you are somewhat unfamiliar with the terminology with JS OOP. Are those two functions constructors? Also, how are you trying to put the objects into the array? How many should be in the array, and what should their values be?

Comment: Agreed -- If we are supposed to tell you why the code you tried isn't working, we'd need to see that code.

Comment: One moment, I will give a better example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`obj2.loadArray();` returns undefined as there is no `return` statement in its implementation.

But if you log into console with this:

```
 console.log(obj2.arr);
```

the console shall display the `[objectOne { a=4, b=4}]` array as expected.

Comment: I must have something else messing this up because I keep getting "Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference"